# Skip N bytes every M bytes while reading from named pipe

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, pipe

I pipe data from one process to another, but this stream needs to be filtered. 
The first process is `ffmpeg` and the second is `ffplay`. `ffmpeg` provides raw video frame for `fplay` to render, however it adds [32 bytes header to each frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390694/video-moves-sideways-when-captured-raw-from-camera-and-piped-into-ffplay/52399554#52399554). For 720p frame, this means that every 1280x720x4 bytes are prepended with 32 bytes.

This affects `ffplay` playback and I need to have some filtering of this byte stream which will drop this header for each frame. Most likely, tools like `od` or `xxd` should be used, but I have difficulties figuring out how exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -e 'print substr $buff, 32 while sysread *STDIN, $buff, 1280 * 720 * 4 + 32'
```

See [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) and [sysread](http://p3rl.org/sysread).

There might be a problem if SSIZE_MAX on your platform is less than 1280 * 720 * 4 + 32, or for some other reason you can't read all the bytes at once. Maybe try this Perl script instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($BLOCK_SIZE, $HEADER_SIZE) = (3686400, 32);

while (1) {
    my $block_size = 0;
    my $block = "";
    my $buff_size;
    while (1) {
        $buff_size = sysread *STDIN, my $buff,
                             $HEADER_SIZE + $BLOCK_SIZE - $block_size;
        last unless $buff_size;

        $block .= $buff;
        $block_size += $buff_size;
    }
    last unless $block_size;

    substr $block, 0, $HEADER_SIZE, "";
    print $block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it, but for some reason, it cuts out more bytes than specified. For example, when I save 1 frame of a video into a file after subtracting 1 byte, in fact, resulting file is missing 57 bytes: `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -pixel_format 0rgb -framerate 25 -video_size 1280x720 -i "0" -map 0:v -c copy -f rawvideo -vframes 1 - |  perl -e 'print substr $buff, 1 while sysread *STDIN, $buff, 3686432' > /tmp/frame.0rgb`. Count bytes `wc -c /tmp.frame.0rgb`

Comment: I tried it with `echo {a..z} | sed 's/ //g'` and it correctly outputs `cdefgjklmnqrstuxyz` for 5 + 2. Check your numbers.

Comment: Can you try this: `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=3686432 count=1 > /tmp/random` which gives 3686432 random bytes (`wc -c /tmp/random`) and then `cat /tmp/random | perl -e 'print substr $buff, 32 while sysread *STDIN, $buff, 3686432' > /tmp/truncated` -- expected to give 3686400 but it's not -- gives 3684256 bytes instead (`wc -c /tmp/truncated`).

Comment: @peeton: It works for me. What perl version do you have?

Comment: weird: `This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level (with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)`

Comment: I'm on v5.18.2 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi :-o

Comment: Also, the difference is 2^5 * 67.

Comment: Maybe a problem with SSIZE_MAX?

Comment: @peetonn: Please, try with the more complex script.